# What is the stable version for cakePHP to build a project?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to migrate the existing project which was built on cakePHP 2.9 version to cakePHP Latest stable version.

Please help me on how to migrate the entire controllers and models to the latest version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current stable version is 3.6. Cakephp upgrade tool will help you with the process. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html

Comment: Beware that the changes to the ORM mean that you're in for a pretty major overhaul. I believe it's worth it for all the benefits, but it's not just a simple upgrade.